# Plotting Just the Seasonal Component of ETS Model - R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

This is probably a simple question but my R skills are still in the learning stages.  I am trying to get just a plot of the seasonal component in an ETS time series model and I also would like the x axis to show the months.  The code below will produce the following graph, what I want is to take the last section (season) and make it a single graph where also the x axis shows not just the years but the months.

```
library(datasets)
fit <- ets(AirPassengers)
plot(fit)
```

[image: ETS Plot]

I tried to find the right component of the fit object but I was unsuccessful in isolating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fit$states[,"s1"]` is season's ts.data. Package `xts` help you with the format of date.

```
library(datasets); library(xts); library(forecast)

fit <- ets(AirPassengers)
season <- fit$states[,"s1"]

plot(as.xts(season), major.format = "%Y-%m", auto.grid=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed.  I was thinking it was the "s1" portion of fit$states but I couldn't find any documentation on it and my general r knowledge is just enough to be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- ets(AirPassengers)
plot.2=function (x, ...){
    if (!is.null(x$lambda)) 
 y <- BoxCox(x$x, x$lambda)
    else y <- x$x
    plot(cbind(season = x$states[,"s1"]), main = paste("Decomposition by", x$method, 
            "method"), ...)
}

plot.2(fit)
```

You may want to have a look at `plot.ets`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works as well as the one I marked as the answer, it looks like the other was first (can't tell to be honest) but I gave you an upvote for your help, wish I could give you both the check.  Thanks again.